# usb internet option unavailable kitkat - reverse tethering

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat, android-internet, tethering

I have Micromax Canvas A1 (android one) with Kitkat 4.4.4 stock android OS.

Mine is an unrooted device & I want to use PC internet for downloading / surfing on my android device.

Going by internet posts and videos they say that one should have 'USB Internet' option available in Wireless & networks menu. But I cant find it on my phone.

Has this 'USB Internet' feature been taken out in kitkat ?

I dont want to root my device yet. Can you please tell me how to reverse tether using USB ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

It has not been taken out but in order to access it you must first access your developer options. This can vary from phone but if you Google "access developer options" and your phone make and model. Then you should get an explanation. From there you will want to enable developer options and then USB debugging. Once enabled, go to your wifi & networks option. Hit more, then hit tethering & portable hotspot. Then you should see USB tethering and you should be able to activate it. Best of luck!

Comment: You misinterpreted the op's question. He is not asking about USB tethering but about USB internet, which is also known as REVERSE USB tethering.